# Как получить время простоя компьютера?

Tags: windows, .net, visual-basic, visual-studio

Как выполнить некоторое событие, если компьютер простаивает определённое время. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую-нибудь умную API-функцию. Или если таких нет или вы знаете, как отследить движение мыши вне окна своего приложения, и/или когда оно неактивно, то поделитесь советом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно, вам нужно это:
[`GetLastInputInfo` (Windows API)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx)

Только начиная с висты эта функция отдаёт структуру только для текущего пользователя - т.е. в сервисе использовать не получится.

Comment: о Господи, именно это мне и нужно!... спасибо тебе, добрый человек. «Только начиная с висты эта функция отдаёт структуру только для текущего пользователя» _ в моей программе это совсем не важно =) тем более она и так работает в одном юзернэйме

Answer (score 2):

- Способ №1: [Управление назначенными заданиями средствами командной строки. Часть 2](http://dimanb.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81-5/)
- Способ №2: [Task Scheduler Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383608%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Обратите внимание, что второе требует минимум Windows Vista.

Comment: Спешу заметить, что "минимум Windows Vista" вышла аж в 2006г., т.е. уже более 4х лет назад.. уже пора бы.. пора слазить с XP...

Comment: Да ладно вам. Уже давно пора бы слазить с Windows ;)

Comment: Windows 7 вполне радует.) Я как-то пытался на Ubuntu перейти, но чё-то никак.. через месяцок всё равно вернулся. А так если переходить, то новичкам на Ubuntu самое то будет...

Comment: А можно чуть поподробнее про 'Способ №1'?

Comment: Респект! Я не знал что у винды появились такие продвинутые возможности.

@BStudio, пройдите по ссылке и прочитайте, там все подробно описано.

Comment: @Сергей, @KmUsr, это далеко не то что мне нужно.. Мне нужно чтобы в программном коде при простаивании компьютера 10 минут выполнялось событие (Sub). Способ 2, я не знаю, наверняка, это то что мне нужно но я туповат и по-английски не гуру.

Comment: Кстати, вы извините меня... я путаю 'событие' (event) и 'процедуру' (sub). Просто привычка дурацкая - называть процедуры событиями, а события эвентами =D

Answer (score 0):

А что значит простаивает? Вы имеете в виду анализ загрузки процессора? Используйте [PerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx).

Если речь об отлове движения мыши и клавиатуры везде, то прочтите [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx). Чтобы понять откуда ноги растут, прочтите [How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;318804)

Comment: Второе)

Comment: Вообще, я бы обратил внимание на ругающегося товарища, которого удалили за ненормативное поведение. Он в своём огромном повествовании о том, какие все козлы и тупицы говорил о том, что есть какой-то способ заскедьюлить таску на IDLE, но сам не сообщил, как же это сделать.

Comment: IDLE.. я слышал о такой штуковине.. но это по-моему только на своё приложение...

Comment: <Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#> думаю будет работать..

Comment: =( ... epic fail. Там полностью си-шарп, а мне нужен висуал басик... а переводить.. я там свихнусь. не гуру си-шарпа =)

Comment: Хуки на васике не пишут, так как либа будет грузится ко всем шадов-процессам, а компиль этот один из худших. Заглючит вся ось =)

Comment: у меня Visual Studio 2010 Ultim. Скажешь худший компилятор ?!!! >.<