# Получить время неподвижности мыши java

Tags: java, мышь, курсор

Здравствуйте. Нужно получить время простоя мыши на Java. Т.е., чтобы метод (или класс) подсчитывал время неподвижности мыши и возвращал его. Пишу на JavaFX.
Может кто сталкивался или знает решение, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Или, хотя бы, куда копать.
Спасибо.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Копайте в сторону  MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation(). Сделайте класс, с полями x,y, totaltime. В цикле с задержкой в 1мс получайте таким способом координаты и сверяйте с теми, что в x,y. Если не отличаются - увеличивайте totaltime. В обратном случае(если отличаются) - записывайте новые и выводите значение totaltime

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться.

Comment: Сейчас набросаю вам примерчик

Comment: Если Вам не сложно. Вообще было бы замечательно.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/7170/178988 - а если так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так.

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;

/**
 *
 * @author chubatiy
 */
public class StartMe {

    public static int x = 0;
    public static int y = 0;
    public static long totaltime = 0L;
    public static final long DELAY = 500L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Получаем текущие координаты
        x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
        y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
        //цикл
        while (true) {
            //получаем текущие координаты
            int newx = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
            int newy = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
            //если координаты отличаются от ранее записанных(предидкщих)
            if ((y != newy || x != newx)) {
                //выводим время
                System.out.println(totaltime);
                //обнуляем время простоя
                totaltime = 0L;
                //запоминаем текщие координаты
                y = newy;
                x = newx;
            } else {
                //иначе увеличиваем время на наш интервал
                totaltime += DELAY;
            }
            //задержка для проверки(т.е. проверяем не изменились ли координаты DELAY мс)
            try {
                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример так себе, но может, поможет Вам понять, куда копать далее и как адаптировать "под себя"

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать.

Comment: Если ответ Вам подходит - поставьте галочку, что ответ верен. Чтобы вопрос больше не "болтался" в секции "без ответа"

Comment: Да, еще раз спасибо. Нашел похожий пример и для javafx.

Comment: Отлично! Поздравляю